# Apache Nifi Single Nar File Update

Tags: apache-nifi

Is it possible update single component in apache nifi

For example I use avro component

Can I only upgrade single **.nar** file without upgrade all nifi components from **1.14** to **1.15**?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-avro-record-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-avro-record-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If yes how can I do that is it enough to copy new nar file version to extension path

Comment: If you haven't configured a separate location  for custom jars then you can put jar inside `lib`. If `1.15.2` version has backward compatibility support then this shouldn't break NiFi otherwise the Maven build process will show errors. You can quickly test this locally by having `1.14`  NiFi version running and replacing the desired jar from `1.15.2`  release. If there is any compatibility issue then NiFi won't start and you will see some exceptions in the log.

Comment: I already try this issue but if I do that time my used component use old version and I have to manuelly update .Is there any nifi command or graphical interface to do that